# Regex pattern to match all characters in string ignore order

Tags: regex

Trying to write pattern to match sequence of characters in string, f.e `dClv`

my pattern is: `(?i)([dClv]{4})`

and it's matches strings like: `lcvd`, `LcVd`, `aaaadclv44444` and so on, but if there is any char in string between any of required, f.e `daClv` or `daCalav`, pattern not matches..

Why?

Comment: So you just want to ensure that all the 4 characters are _anywhere_ in the string at least once?

Comment: Perhaps like this `\b(?:[^dClv\s]*[dClv]){4}[^dClv\s]*\b` https://regex101.com/r/tc4HEC/1

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen right

Comment: Use look ahead: (?=.*d)(?=.*C)(?=.*l)(?=.*v)

Comment: What programming langugage?
Generally you can put "/i" for making it case-insensitive.

Comment: Or as it is case insensitive `\b(?:[abe-km-uw-z0-9]*[dClv]){4}[abe-km-uw-z0-9]*\b`  https://regex101.com/r/CHfi7k/1

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?i)(?:[dClv][^dClv]*){3}[dClv]
```

This matches 4 required chars with any chars but the required chars in between. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/yO9ary/1).